# Using here-api map with capacitor

Tags: here-api

We are using here api for the map on our website and it works nicely. For the first version of a mobile app we are using capacitor to wrap our website and have a mobile app. The problem now is that the host of our mobile app is capacitor://xxx.xxx. Now we get an 401 when trying to load the map inside the mobile app. We have added capacitor://xxx.xxx as a trusted domain. But I guess it only allows http and https. What can we do to prevent this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HERE JS API is product that intended to work via online connectivity. Therefore is fully supported **https://** protocol scheme.

http:// and file:// - they are working but with some limitations.

Unfortunately, any custom protocol like capacitor:// is not supported.

Comment: That's so sad, Google also supports a bunch of other protocols for key restriction, like ionic://, chrome:// etc. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key For us, this  is why we have to switch to Google, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna try this soon. But the problem should be avoidable by using the native http capacitor plugin. As I read this resolves all CORS problems so this could be included.

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/http

Gonna update the answer once I have tried it.

UPDATE: With version 3.1.36 everything seems to work even if I request via the cordova:// context, if you had a 401 maybe your token was wrong?